# Styling an xml recursively using xslt

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, styles

I'm trying to stylize a large xml document to make the information readable and organized. I'm treating every tag as necessary data that needs to be visible to the user. I want to stylize the  hierarchy of the nodes with visual weight (ie. parent nodes will have a h2(html header tag) and the values of the nodes will have a < p> html tag.).

**Problem:** I don't know all the tags location and what information is important. Rather than me creating an array and listing each node to display. Could I just recursively code the xslt in such a way that it will stylize the parents node as: ./* = < h1>, ./*/* = < h2> ./*/*/*=< h3> ./*/*/*=< h4>... etc.

I know there is something wrong with my logic. My google-fu lead me to xpath where I used ./* and ./child* but it doesn't seem to print the siblings correctly in the xslt. I have provided the xslt code below. I'm open to suggestions using css or other functions to help stylize the XML document.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="./*"/> </h1>
      <xsl:for-each select="./*">
         <h2><xsl:value-of select="./*"/> </h2>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <h3><xsl:value-of select="./*"/> </h3>
                   <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                   <h4><xsl:value-of select="./*"/> </h4>
                   </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit: 4/12/2022**
Sorry I wasn't clear earlier. I was tryin to solve my issues one at a time rather than dumping all the issues in one post. I know I have to incorporate name() into the XSLT, but for the sake of savin time, if the input XML is like this:

```
INPUT XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist> Boogaloo 
      <first>Bonnie </first>
      <last> Tyler </last>
     </artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

```
EXPECTED XSLT OUTPUT:

<h1>catalog</h1>
<h2>cd</h2>

<h3>title :</h3> <p> Empire Burlesque </p>
<h3>artist : </h3> <p> Bob Dylan </p>
<h3> country : </h3> <p> USA </p>
<h3> company : </h3> <p> Columbia </p>
<h3> price : </h3> <p> 10.90 </p>
<h3> year : </h3> <p> 1985 </p>

<h2>cd</h2>
<h3>title :</h3> <p> Hide your heart </p>
<h3>artist : </h3> <p> Boogaloo </p>
<h4>first: </h3> <p>Bonnie </p>
<h4>last: </h3> <p>Tyler </p>
<h3> country : </h3> <p> UK </p>
<h3> company : </h3> <p> CBS Records </p>
<h3> price : </h3> <p> 9.90 </p>
<h3> year : </h3> <p> 1988 </p>

<h2>cd</h2>
<h3>title :</h3> <p> Greatest Hits </p>
<h3>artist : </h3> <p> Dolly Parton </p>
<h3> country : </h3> <p> USA </p>
<h3> company : </h3> <p> RCA </p>
<h3> price : </h3> <p> 9.90 </p>
<h3> year : </h3> <p> 1982 </p>
```

Comment: If you can post your XML and the expected output it'll help everyone help you.

Comment: I don't see your posted code trying to create `h1`, `h2`, `h3` etc. elements at all. As for recursion, yes, that is the natural processing model if you rely on `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and template matching with e.g. `xsl:template match`. I don't see how HTML with 6 heading levels helps to style any XML (of any depth?) and it is not clear what kind of information you want to put in a heading and what content of an element you want to output further.

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample XML and the intended output.  Just want to point out the reason I  am doing this is because I have a large xml document and want to make the information readable and organized. My challenge is to add visual weight to each parent node and display its value in a < p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thee are two ways you can track an element's depth in the hierarchy of the XML input:

1. Use a *parameter* and increase its value at each level; here's a simple example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:param name="depth" select="1"/>
    <xsl:element name="h{$depth}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2. Count the number of current element's ancestors:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="h{count(ancestor-or-self::*)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using your example input, the result in both cases will be:

**Result**

```
<h1>catalog</h1>
<h2>cd</h2>
<h3>title</h3>
<p>Empire Burlesque</p>
<h3>artist</h3>
<p>Bob Dylan</p>
<h3>country</h3>
<p>USA</p>
<h3>company</h3>
<p>Columbia</p>
<h3>price</h3>
<p>10.90</p>
<h3>year</h3>
<p>1985</p>
<h2>cd</h2>
<h3>title</h3>
<p>Hide your heart</p>
<h3>artist</h3>
<p> Boogaloo 
         
</p>
<h4>first</h4>
<p>Bonnie </p>
<h4>last</h4>
<p> Tyler </p>
<h3>country</h3>
<p>UK</p>
<h3>company</h3>
<p>CBS Records</p>
<h3>price</h3>
<p>9.90</p>
<h3>year</h3>
<p>1988</p>
<h2>cd</h2>
<h3>title</h3>
<p>Greatest Hits</p>
<h3>artist</h3>
<p>Dolly Parton</p>
<h3>country</h3>
<p>USA</p>
<h3>company</h3>
<p>RCA</p>
<h3>price</h3>
<p>9.90</p>
<h3>year</h3>
<p>1982</p>
```

which seems to be the result you want, although not a valid HTML document.

Comment: This is excellent. 

One follow up question. Instead of using Header, how would I do it to a customized style like different font size and colour. Would I just include something like this in the above code for :
`
<xsl:attribute-set name="smallerFont">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size"> "{count(ancestor-or-self::*)}+14" pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
`

Comment: I am afraid I cannot advise you how to produce a result without knowing what the wanted result is.  I *think* that if you want to use CSS to denote the depth, you could do something like `<div class="level{$depth}">`. Then add a CSS that has a style for `div.level1`, `div.level2`, etc.